# Issue Firefox text-overflow:ellipsis on child element

Tags: css, firefox

With a parent div and a child div

```
<div class="div-parent">
    <div class="div-child">
        Oportunum est, ut arbitror, explanare nunc causam.
    </div>
</div>
```

Using text-overflow: ellipsis on the div parent

```
.div-parent {
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.div-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

On Chrome, the text is truncated and '...' are added as wanted.

But on Firefox, the text is only truncated...

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbp_hipay/wjpy1q5x/25/)

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* Firefox is doing the right thing because technically the child div is set to `inline-block` so it will fit its content and it will overflow the parent element. So the `inline-block` is overflowing not the text.

You should make the child `width:100%` to have a text overflow and move the properties to the child div:

```css
.div-parent {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.div-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-parent">
  <div class="div-child">
    Oportunum est, ut arbitror, explanare nunc causam, quae ad exitium praecipitem Aginatium inpulit iam inde a priscis maioribus nobilem, ut locuta est pertinacior fama. nec enim super hoc ulla documentorum rata est fides.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I agree, but, this style is defined in a library I use, I wanted to understand why it was not working on firefox before entering in the library style.

Comment: @ThomasBihan-Poudec the quesiton is maybe: why it's working on Chrome? .. for me it seems that Chrome shouldn't add ellipsis